# logstash config error:Unknown setting 'start_position' for file {:level=>:error}

Tags: logstash

I am learning elk, and there is a problem with the config file:logstash.config here is the config:

```
input {
       file {
             path => "E:/elk/log/access_test.log"
             start_position => beginning
       }
}
filter { 
       grok { 
             match => {
                "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"
             }
       }
       date {
             locale => "en"
             match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z", "ISO8601" ]
       }
}
output {
        file {
              path => "E:/elk/log/logstash-access_test.log"
              start_position => beginning
       }
}
```

when I run the config, the title's error will come out. Can anybody tell me the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Output file plugin does not have `start_position`  attribute try this.

```
input {
       file {
             path => "E:/elk/log/access_test.log"
             start_position => beginning
       }
}
filter { 
        grok { 
              match => {
                        "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"
              }
        }
        date {
              locale => "en"
              match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z", "ISO8601" ]
        }
}
output {
       file {
             path => "E:/elk/log/logstash-access_test.log"
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also in case it helps, invoke logstash with --configtest should give you more information - in particular the line/col number.

Hopefully this will confirm the issue is in output not input...